# Google App Script If Condition is giving no answer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've trying to add an if condition.

**Condition one** If the down payment is below `35%` of the price then `"Your downpayment should be above 35% of the price"`

**Condition two** If the down payment is above `100%` of the price then `"your downpayment should be below 100% of the price"`

**condition three** if the downpayment is between 35%-100% then do the math.

The answer isn't working in my below coding, where did I go wrong?

```
 if(parseInt(downPayment) < 0.35*parseInt(vprice) || parseInt(downPayment) = parseInt(vprice)) {
  
  document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = "Your downpayment should be minimum 35% of the price - "  +" (↑"+ nf.format((Math.round(vprice*0.35))) +")";
  
  }
  
  
  else if(parseInt(downPayment) > parseInt(vprice)) {
  
  document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = "Your downpayment should be below 100% of the price - "  +" (↑"+ nf.format((Math.round(vprice*0.100))) +")";
  
  }
  
  else {
  
  document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = " 1st Year Monthly Rental: "+ nf.format((Math.round(month))) + "<br>2nd Year Monthly Rental: " +  nf.format((Math.round(month2))) + "<br>3rd Year Monthly Retal:"+  nf.format((Math.round(month3))) ;
  google.script.run.userClicked({
    vprice,
    downPayment,
    rate,
    period,
    month
  });
  //sending to HTML by ID
  document.getElementById("subL").innerHTML = "Sub Loan - "+  nf.format((Math.round(subL)));
  document.getElementById("YearBulk1").innerHTML = "1st Year End Bulk Payment - "+ nf.format((Math.round(YearBulk1)));
 document.getElementById("YearBulk2").innerHTML = "2nd Year End Bulk Payment - "+ nf.format((Math.round(YearBulk2)));
 document.getElementById("YearBulk3").innerHTML = "3rd Year End Bulk Payment - "+ nf.format((Math.round(YearBulk3)));
  
  
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

- You have a typo in the first `if` statement; it should be `==` instead
  of `=` but you can also simplify the expression by using `<=`.
- You must put `document.getElementById("month").innerHTML` outside of the `if` conditions, otherwise the rest of the elements won't be send to the webpage.
- I also used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to simplify your expression and make it more futureproof as well.

---

**Solution:**

```
if(parseInt(downPayment) <= 0.35*parseInt(vprice) ) {
  var resm = `Your downpayment should be minimum 35% of the price - (↑ ${nf.format((Math.round(vprice*0.35)))})`;
  }
  
  
  else if(parseInt(downPayment) > parseInt(vprice)) {
    var resm = `Your downpayment should be below 100% of the price - (↑ ${nf.format((Math.round(vprice*0.100)))})`;
  }
  
  else {
var resm = `1st Year Monthly Rental: ${nf.format((Math.round(month)))} <br>2nd Year Monthly Rental: ${nf.format((Math.round(month2)))} <br>3rd Year Monthly Retal: ${nf.format((Math.round(month3)))}`;
  }


  document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = resm;
  google.script.run.userClicked({
    vprice,
    downPayment,
    rate,
    period,
    month
  })

  //sending to HTML by ID
  document.getElementById("subL").innerHTML = "Sub Loan - "+  nf.format((Math.round(subL)));
  document.getElementById("YearBulk1").innerHTML = "1st Year End Bulk Payment - "+ nf.format((Math.round(YearBulk1)));
 document.getElementById("YearBulk2").innerHTML = "2nd Year End Bulk Payment - "+ nf.format((Math.round(YearBulk2)));
 document.getElementById("YearBulk3").innerHTML = "3rd Year End Bulk Payment - "+ nf.format((Math.round(YearBulk3)));
```

Comment: How to make disappear of the  //sending to HTML by ID ?

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil I am not quite sure what you mean. Could you please post a separate question for that? :) Stackoverflow does not allow follow-up questions.

Comment: I figured it out after few placement changes. Thanks  :)

Comment: Anyware I'll post another question just to ensure I'm made it all perfect. Please check and let me know

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil why don't you just delete it if you don't want it?

Comment: I want to appear if the conditions are met i.e. the downpayment is between 35%-%100 else it has to show only the error message.

Comment: @MuhammedAadhil then your code is correct. You should put it in the else statement.